Rules upon % at end of line
When writing macros, the trailing comment character is used to ignore the rest of the input line, suppressing spaces, and the end of line character that is appended gets ignored too.
Which aspects of a general macro definition would require an trailing  % at the end of lines ?  Although I have seen long explanations, I find them too terse and super detailed, that confuse me.

Welcome. (But I am pretty sure I already said this.) I think you have run into a disconnect between the way the site is supposed to operate (according to SE) and the way it actually operates (on TeX SE). This is exacerbated by somebody's use of a golden sledge hammer to close your question instantly. (This is not really entirely consistent with that person's stated policy on Meta, but (1) I may be misunderstanding and (2) it may not have been deliberate as it is easy to do by mistake.) Could you clarify whether the answers to the linked question answer your own? If not, we can reopen this.

as I wrote in a comment that was auto-deleted when the post was closed, the duplicate shows when to use it. Strictly speeking it is never needed. \fbox{ a } is not wrong it is just different to \fbox{a}  If you do not want the white space either do not add it, or comment it out with % but if you do want the white space then having it after { is correct.

@cfr I closed it, I did leave a longish specific comment before referencing the duplicate rather than "just close" but I forgot the system deletes comments that mention the duplicate if it ends up being closed so it now looks a bit abrupt, hopefully the OP got the comment via the ping in any case.

@DavidCarlisle Have you ever seen a deleted comment? Judging by the edit, I'm guessing the OP didn't. I suspect pings vanish with comments, but a priori predictions of phenomena are notoriously unreliable.

@DavidCarlisle But I'm sorry if my comment seemed mean. I didn't intend it that way.

@cfr well you see it if you see it before it's deleted. No, it wasn't mean: closing with no comment (or a comment the system decides to remove) isn't good.

The linked answer is too complicated, rather than giving examples of when % is customarily required when writing macros.

@Liccu At present the questions do seem to be the same: if you feel the older one doesn't get the 'right' answers, you could seek an additional answer there or could edit here to make the question distinct

The comment character can be used outside the context of the source code of a macro-definition, too. You use it in the .tex-input-file whenever you wish to avoid that at the time of reading and tokenizing the .tex-file the remaining characters of the line of the .tex-file get tokenized and yield appending tokens to the token-stream. Whether tokens of the token-stream end up as components of macro definitions or as s.th. else doesn't matter. Thus it is not clear to me why with your question the focus is on writing macros.

@Liccu In the “Linked” column of the duplicate question you can find several questions, that also contain examples of where “%” at end of lines are needed. One more can be found at How to avoid unwanted spaces in the output.
